# Spreadsheet: Find Another Cell With The Same Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice-calc

I have a column of names; Each name has exactly 1 duplicate, Is there a function I can use to find the row number of the 2nd copy of the name.

[image: Sample Data]

So the values should be 2,1,4,3,6,5,7,6 and so on.

In the above example, the duplicates exist just below  each other but they could be in any order

Comment: isnt row 1 Team and there is no duplicate of Team therefore row 1 should not be part of your answer set?

Comment: Yup, row 1 is just the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula :

`=IFERROR(MATCH(A2,A3:A$1000,0)+ROW(), MATCH(A2,A$1:A1,0)+ROW(A$1)-1)`

The key is to split your data before & after current range and use absolute / relative references correctly.

[image]

Comment: hey... looks like you have the same problem I have sometimes with super-large images. If you want to make it smaller and it's hosted on imgur, you can just put an "m" in the image file name immediately before the period and extension. So instead of file.png, you can change it to filem.png

Comment: @FlexYourData love the helpful tip.  I am more apt to give a +1 just for being able to do that work on a cell phone!